# how to get touch event after a button click in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIButton` in my project and after a button click I am showing a `UIView` on the top of that button in such a way that the button remains hidden that time. I want to get a `touchesmoved` event on that time when I keep that button pressed and move finger over the overlapped `UIView`. As far as I did is like the following:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == uiview)
    {

        NSLog(@"Touches moved");
    }
```

but it doesnt get called when I keep the button pressed that is hidden when the `UIView` comes up and the uiview goes hidden when I release the button. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Can you show some code how to bring this view up and hide the button? It would be easier.

Comment: I have taken a uiview in the xib on the top of that button and kept it hidden. when I click on the button make the uiview becomes visible and when i release the button the uiview becomes invisible again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quiet understand what your trying to do but I would suggest you use UIGestureRecognizers and add Gestures Recognizers to your button.

Try using this code. I've used this in a card game i developed. moving cards around using long press gestures. Hope i helps.

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addLongpressGesture:)];
 [longPress setDelegate:self];
 [YOUR_BUTTON addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

- (void)addLongpressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

UIView *view = sender.view;

CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:view.superview];

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){ 

      // GESTURE STATE BEGAN

}
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){

     //GESTURE STATE CHANGED/ MOVED

    CGPoint center = view.center;
    center.x += point.x - _priorPoint.x;
    center.y += point.y - _priorPoint.y;
    view.center = center;

    // This is how i drag my views
  }

 else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

      //GESTURE ENDED
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set view.userInteractionEnabled = NO for your overlapped UIView. 
This will send action to button.